# Check PID of caller in startCommand() in Android service

Tags: android

Is there a way to check the PID of the caller who called `startService(intent)` inside of  `Service.startCommand(Intent, int, int)`?

Comment: Have you tried with `android.os.Process.myPid()` ?

Comment: Calling that method inside of the service will give you the PID of the service itself, I want the PID of the caller who started my service. This is for security purposes, only someone in my process is allowed to call certain actions on my service (other applications can start my service for other actions too, that don't require this check).

Comment: When you start new service you can pass the PID of the caller to the called process. No?

Comment: But that's not secure, anyone can pass the service it's own PID.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know other solution